# Prevent SQL connection from timing out

Tags: python, mysql

so I'm using a SQL database for a discord bot I'm working on. Everything is fine until SQL times out while the code is running overnight which then gives an error anytime someone actually uses the bot during the day. If there some way to either refresh the connection or to remove this inactivity timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's two solutions to this the more correct one is to switch to mysql alchemy and have that deal with the issue. or the other one is to have a timer that refreshes the connect after a while like this.

Warning: This is psedo code so you might have to adapt it a bit

```py
import time
import mysql.connector

refreshTime = time.time() + 3600 # Set the refreshTime to the last connected time plus the time it will take to timeout

def refresh():
    if time.time() > refreshTime:
        DB = connector.connect(database stuff)
        conn = DB.cursor()
    # Don't need an else block because the later code refreshes the DB connection
    refreshTime = time.time() + 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use uptime robot to keep pinging the code every 5 mins or so

https://uptimerobot.com/